# How to accept a list of IDs to process in an action method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC action method that accepts a single policyId and processes it, returning a JSON result to indicate success.

```
public ActionResult MovePolicyToFallout(int policyId)
{
    try
    {
        orchestrator.MovePolicyToFallout(policyId);
        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        return HttpNotFound(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What is a good pattern to make this code accept a list of policyId and process each of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the method you have, then add a method that takes a collection of values and loops over them, calling your method for each one:

```
public List<ActionResult> MovePoliciesToFallout(List<int> policyIds)
{
    var l = new List<ActionResult>();

    foreach (int policyId in policyIds)
    {
        var result = MovePolicyToFallout(policyId);
        l.Add(result);
    }

    return l;
}
```

Note: it will return a list of results, naturally, rather than one.

Comment: Why are you returning a `List<ActionResult>`?

Comment: @mason -- one for each input policy ID, naturally.

Comment: No....unnaturally. This looks like an MVC or Web API controller. Returning a `List<ActionResult>` makes no sense. An action method should only return one `ActionResult`. That ActionResult might actually be a `JsonResult` that contains the status of each thing, but still just one resulting object.

Comment: Yea, it is MVC controller. I am thinking about use IEnumerable<int>. any ideal?

Comment: @mason -- okay, but that wasn't part of the question.  It's not tagged as MVC nor is that mentioned anywhere in the question.  It's the most natural thing to assume in a general case (which it is, due to the lack of more-specific tags).  I don't work with ASP.NET, so for all I knew, `ActionResult` was a custom class.

Comment: I have now tagged it as MVC. And even if it wasn't tagged, you can tell because it was using ActionResult and returning `HttpNotFound` etc.

Comment: @mason -- no, I can't tell.  Because I don't work with the technology you're assuming everyone knows.  If it had been properly tagged, I would have just ignored the question altogether.  Since that was not the case, it looks like I've just wasted my time here.

Comment: I don't think you've wasted your time. It would be pretty simple to update your answer to be valid. Have it return a single ActionResult, probably a JsonResult like it's originally doing in the question.

Comment: @mason -- but wouldn't it have to be an aggregate of the results from all the input values?

Comment: Sure would. Look at Stuart's answer for one way of doing that. One object being returned, but within it are the results of the attempted operations.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider changing the flow of control, such that `MovePolicyToFallout` does not throw an exception if it can't find the policy.

e.g. below, I've assumed that instead of throwing, the called method returns a boolean.

You can then project the entire list of results, keyed by the PolicyIds:

```
public ActionResult MovePoliciesToFallout(IEnumerable<int> policyIds)
{
    return Json(policyIds.Select(
      pId => new 
      {
            PolicyId = pId,
            Success = orchestrator.MovePolicyToFallout(pId)
      }));
}
```

Comment: I would have personally used a foreach loop and built up a list instead of a select statement, but I totally agree it should return a boolean instead of throwing an exception to indicate failure.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in a 200 (OK) even in the case of failure?  I see no reason to return `Success` in the JSON response either.  Throwing and letting the pipeline handle it makes more sense.  If you wanted to return a boolean, I'd use the boolean to decide whether to return a result with a different HTTP status code.

Comment: @MattJohnson It depends on what you mean by failure. If it was an unexpected failure (an exception) then it would go through the normal MVC error handling. If it was an expected failure, then an exception shouldn't be used and the return signature should accommodate for that.

Comment: @ChengYang You'll need to change `orchestrator.MovePolicyToFallout` to return a boolean that indicates whether it was successful or not, instead of marking it as void.

Comment: @MattJohnson - You are right, it will always return Ok (unless there are ambient handlers for other conditions like exceptions). OP is essentially asking for a batch processing command service. A single Http response code isn't going to cut it for multiple commands, so the best we can do is indicate that we acknowledge the batch (Ok), and then indicate the outcome of each transaction, keyed by its id. If the `MovePolicyToFallout` processing is IO bound, this would also be a good candidate for async / await, and potentially `Task.WhenAll` parallellisation.

Answer (score 0):

An update of rory.ap's post, use a List and a foreach loop

```
public List<ActionResult> MovePoliciesToFallout(List<int> policyIds)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (int policyId in policyIds)
        {
            MovePolicyToFallout(policyId);
        }
    }
    catch(EntityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        return HttpNotFound(ex.Message);
    }

    return Json(new { Success = true }); //or return view, redirecttoaction etc
}
```